# Rabbitmq -> epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all?

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

```
ubuntu@hostname:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server start
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                        [ OK ]
ubuntu@hostname:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server  stop
 * Stopping message broker rabbitmq-server                                                * message broker already stopped
                                                                              [ OK ]
ubuntu@hostname:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node 'rabbit@hostname' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@hostname': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@hostname']

rabbit@hostname:
* connected to epmd (port 4369) on hostname
* epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
              no other nodes on hostname
* suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-19082@hostname'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq 
- cookie hash: Zoi/1N8mjGUsELj8Z7yzoA==

ubuntu@hostname:~$
```

I tried to reset it using `sudo rabbitmqctl reset` and `sudo rabbitmqctl force_reset` both did not work.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33935430/12484

Answer (score 13, accepted):

remove /var/log/rabbitmq/* and start it back

from :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/w0aJNmfz1N8

Comment: You should add the details here so we don't have to go dig through a google group. Also, that link might not always be available

Comment: So after removing `sudo rm -rf /var/log/rabbitmq/*` , I started `sudo service rabbitmq-server start` and `rabbitmqctl start_app`. It worked, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `/var/lib/rabbitmq/*` instead of **log**?

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a problem with the service not started properly.

After trying the accepted solution I just did an additional

```
service rabbitmqserver restart
```

and it worked. After that, the second node connected without problems again to the other node.

Comment: This worked for me, except it was `service rabbitmq-server restart`

Answer (score 1):

empd report to my knowledge is a part of OTP(Erlang) peer recognition for rabbitmq, installed as a dependency while installing rabbitmq. You can check the erl_crash.dump file to check the reason for the crash and act accordingly.

If you are not able to make anything out of the crash report, you can simply change the rabbitmq.config to default value. I got my rabbitmq like this. You will find the default settings in rabbitmq.congif.example file. Once you are done with this, restart the rabbitmq server and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It was selinux in my case, have a look what is in rabbit log file
/var/log/rabbirmq/(nodename@host).log if it is anything about ports then it might be selinux

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the acces rights correctly, using `chmod 644 /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins` and then start the service again with `service rabbitmq-server restart`

Answer (score 0):

### Fix for similar issue

Got this issue when Rabbitmq got auto-updated under the hood ( maybe due to brew update ) which has breaking changes as it involves a change in the minor version ( `3.8.x` -> `3.9.x` )

After trying for many days I choose to clean install rabbitmq

> Ensure that there are no other important files or data you might want to keep.

[How to clean install rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724001/14853666)