# epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all

Tags: rabbitmq

My RabbitMQ used to run just fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, but suddenly it just refuses to start.

The hostname of the server is `canvas1`.

I installed it using standard apt-get approach:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

I've tried `sudo rm -rf /var/log/rabbitmq/*` suggested by [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/783607/rabbitmq-epmd-reports-node-rabbit-not-running-at-all) and it doesn't help.

I've tried `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/*` then restart, and it didn't work.

I've also tried adding `127.0.0.0  canvas1` to `/etc/hosts`, and adding `export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1` to `/etc/default/rabbitmq-server`, but none of them worked.

I've tried uninstall the rabbitmq-server, purge it, and autoremove and autopurge, then reinstall the rabbitmq-server, and it doesn't work, either.

Here is the log shown by `sudo service rabbitmq-server status`:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-05-20 16:00:11 CST; 7s ago
  Process: 5830 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 5523 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5522 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5522 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]:   * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]:                   no other nodes on canvas1
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]:   * suggestion: start the node
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]: current node details:
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]: - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-5838@canvas1'
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]: - home dir: .
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 rabbitmq[5830]: - cookie hash: KCGs/YQo59BuMnMdMM416A==
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 16:00:11 canvas1 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

and the content in `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log`:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   noproc

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@canvas1.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@canvas1-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{gen,do_for_proc,2,[{file,"gen.erl"},{line,228}]},
    {gen_event,rpc,2,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,239}]},
    {rabbit,ensure_working_log_handlers,0,
            [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,697}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,328}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,356}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]},
    {init,do_boot,3,[]}]

=INFO REPORT==== 20-May-2019::16:00:09.809084 ===
Error description:
   noproc

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@canvas1.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@canvas1-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{gen,do_for_proc,2,[{file,"gen.erl"},{line,228}]},
    {gen_event,rpc,2,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,239}]},
    {rabbit,ensure_working_log_handlers,0,
            [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,697}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,328}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,356}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]},
    {init,do_boot,3,[]}]


{"init terminating in do_boot",noproc}
```

and the content in `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err`:

```
init terminating in do_boot (noproc)

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

and there is no `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@canvas1.log`. All the files in `/var/log/rabbitmq/` is `startup_log` and `startup_err`.

There's no dets files in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` either. Only a pid file there, and there's no process with that pid.

The `erl_crash.dump` can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aRSQ-DXkMUZr2domAB-oc6AbeI6-y07c/view?usp=sharing

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that RabbitMQ does not work well with esl-erlang on Ubuntu, I don't know why though.

After completely uninstalling both RabbitMQ and esl-erlang, then reinstall RabbitMQ only, everything works fine again.